# Adding a monad transformer to the Yesod Handler stack

Tags: haskell, yesod, monad-transformers

How do I add another monad transformer to the Yesod `Handler` stack?

Specifically, I would like to add `CRandT` from `Control.Monad.CryptoRandom` so that I can generate secure random numbers for things like sessions ids and cipher keys.

If I do manage to add this to the stack, will it be shared among calls to the web server or will a new one be generated for each connection? The reason I care is that the latter will use up entropy used to initialize the generator, while the former will keep using the same generator once it is initialized.

Or maybe I'm way off base and completely don't understand monad transformer stacks.

Comment: I think you could do `CRandT g Handler` as your monad, and you'll have to use `runCRandT` or `evalCRandT` before you apply the run function for the `Handler` type.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@bheklilr's idea is definitely an approach you can take. Generally speaking, you can't insert transformers underneath `HandlerT` in Yesod, since the framework wouldn't know how to unwrap it.

There does appear to be another approach: you could keep a random number generator in something like an `IORef` in your foundation datatype, and then define a `MonadCRandom` instance for your specific `HandlerT App IO` monad. I don't have any experience with `MonadCRandom`, so I can't offer an immediate demonstration on how to do it, but I think it shouldn't be too difficult. You could probably base the implementation around the `MonadCRandom` instance for `CRandT`.

Comment: Michael- Funny you should mention it. I just found the wiki page https://github.com/yesodweb/yesod/wiki/Keeping-(in-memory)-state-with-yesod on your web site. Investigating now. Thanks.

Comment: Note that I added an in-depth explanation and demonstration of this to the Yesod book: http://www.yesodweb.com/book/yesods-monads#yesods-monads_adding_a_new_monad_transformer

Comment: Very nice! And it coincidentally answers exactly the question I asked :-).  BTW, when is O'Reilly printing the new version of your book? I want to buy an updated copy.

Comment: I don't have an exact publish date, it depends on when I get them the manuscript, which depends on when I get yesod 1.4 out the door. Likely six months is the upper bound.